# Identifying an UIImageView without tag

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, macos, ipad

I have some generic generated ImageViews in a scrollView each of these images have 2 gestureRecognizer for single/double tapping on the ImageView. Now my problem is how to identify whether the ImageView was tapped for first or second time. In some scenarios it's easy to use the tag of an ImageView, but I have two different gestureRecognizer on each ImageView and every gestureRecognizer uses a different identification method based on the tag number, to identify the image.

Here I generate the ImageViews dynamically:

```
-(void) initLevels{
_level = [Level alloc];
_unit = [Unit alloc];
self->_units = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int i = 0;

for (NSObject *object in self->_levels) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:_level.class] && i != 0) {
        x = x + MARGIN_RIGHT + OBJECT_WIDTH;
        y = 0;
        }
    else if ([object isKindOfClass:_unit.class]){
        _unit = (Unit *) object;
        [self->_units addObject:_unit.description];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.box];
        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, OBJECT_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT)];
        imageView.highlighted = TRUE;
        imageView.tag = i; //when this is not outlined the gestureRecognizer for singleTapping works but on the other hand the double tap gestureRecognizer just works for the first object, because its' tag is set on 0.  

        UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(unitDoubleTapped:)];
        doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGesture];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGesture =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(unitSingleTapped:)];
        singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    //telling the singleTapGesture to fail the doubleTapGesture, so both doesn't fire at the same time
        [singleTapGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapGesture];
        [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGesture];
         UILabel *labelHeadline = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 2, 220, 20)];
        [labelHeadline setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
        labelHeadline.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [labelHeadline setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0]];

        labelHeadline.text = _unit.headline;
        labelHeadline.numberOfLines = 0;
        [labelHeadline sizeToFit];

        UILabel *labelPrice = [LabelUtils deepLabelCopy:labelHeadline withText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Price: %@",_unit.price] withFrame:NO];
        [labelPrice setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        [labelPrice setFrame:CGRectMake(labelHeadline.frame.origin.x, labelHeadline.frame.origin.y + labelHeadline.frame.size.height + 2, 220, 20)];

        UILabel *labelCRM = [LabelUtils deepLabelCopy:labelHeadline withText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CRM: %@", _unit.crm] withFrame:NO];
        [labelCRM setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

        [labelCRM setFrame:CGRectMake(labelPrice.frame.origin.x, labelPrice.frame.origin.y + labelPrice.frame.size.height + 2, 220, 20)];



        UITextView *textView= [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, OBJECT_WIDTH, OBJECT_HEIGHT)];
        [textView addSubview:labelHeadline];
        [textView addSubview:labelPrice];
        [textView addSubview:labelCRM];
        [textView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [textView setEditable:NO];
        textView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0];
        textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [imageView addSubview:textView];
        [_scrollView addSubview:imageView];

        y = y + MARGIN_BOTTOM + BOX_HEIGHT;
    }
    [self->_keys addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    i++;
}//remove the last keys which are to much in the _keys array
while ([self->_keys count] > ([self->_units count])) {
    [_keys removeLastObject];
    i--;
}

self.contents = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:self->_units forKeys:_keys];
 }
```

Here is the code for the two gesture Recognizer

```
-(void)unitDoubleTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
self->_unitViewForDoubleTapIdentification = (UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
switch (self->_unitViewForDoubleTapIdentification.tag) {
    case 0:
        [_unitViewForDoubleTapIdentification setHighlightedImage:self.transparentBox];
        self->_unitViewForDoubleTapIdentification.tag = 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        [_unitViewForDoubleTapIdentification setHighlightedImage:self.box];
       self->_unitViewForDoubleTapIdentification.tag = 0;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

}
```

and Here the singleTap

```
- (IBAction)unitSingleTapped:(id)sender {
[self dismissAllPopTipViews];
UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [UIGestureRecognizer alloc];
gestureRecognizer = (UIGestureRecognizer *)sender;
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView = (UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;

if (sender == _currentPopTipViewTarget) {
    // Dismiss the popTipView and that is all
    self.currentPopTipViewTarget = nil;
}
    NSString *contentMessage = nil;
    UIImageView *contentView = nil;
    NSNumber *key = [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageView.tag];
    id content = [self.contents objectForKey:key];

    if ([content isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        contentMessage = content;
    }
    else {
        contentMessage = @"A large amount ot text in this bubble\najshdjashdkgsadfhadshgfhadsgfkasgfdasfdhasdkfgaodslfgkashjdfg\nsjfkasdfgkahdjsfghajdsfgjakdsfgjjakdsfjgjhaskdfjadsfgjdsfahsdafhjajdskfhadshfadsjfhadsjlfkaldsfhfldsa\ndsfgahdsfgajskdfgkafd";
    }
    NSArray *colorScheme = [_colorSchemes objectAtIndex:foo4random()*[_colorSchemes count]];
    UIColor *backgroundColor = [colorScheme objectAtIndex:0];
    UIColor *textColor = [colorScheme objectAtIndex:1];

    CMPopTipView *popTipView;
    if (contentView) {
        popTipView = [[CMPopTipView alloc] initWithCustomView:contentView];
    }

    else {
        popTipView = [[CMPopTipView alloc] initWithMessage:contentMessage];
    }
    [popTipView presentPointingAtView:imageView inView:self.view animated:YES];
    popTipView.delegate = self;
    popTipView.disableTapToDismiss = YES;
    popTipView.preferredPointDirection = PointDirectionUp;
    if (backgroundColor && ![backgroundColor isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        popTipView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }
    if (textColor && ![textColor isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        popTipView.textColor = textColor;
    }

    popTipView.animation = arc4random() % 2;
    popTipView.has3DStyle = (BOOL)(arc4random() % 2);

    popTipView.dismissTapAnywhere = YES;
    [popTipView autoDismissAnimated:YES atTimeInterval:3.0];

    [_visiblePopTipViews addObject:popTipView];
    self.currentPopTipViewTarget = sender;
     }
```

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Long code not mean a clear question!

Comment: Where you say "every gestureRecognizer uses a different tag number to identify the image", how does your image view have more than one tag?

Comment: I try to reword it otherwise.

Comment: My ImageViews doesn't have more than one tag, but my gestureRecognizer uses different types of identification methods based on the tag number of the imageView e.g. When I double tap on the ImageView the doubleTap method will be called, but it doesn't work anymore due to I say imageView.tag = i; And when you're now looking at the doubleTap method maybe you will see my problem.

Comment: add all imageViews to an array and use `indexOfObject:` and `objectAtIndex:`. If you need to keep a list of specific imageViews save those indexes in a `NSIndexSet`.

Comment: Is the goal to get a reference to the touched view or is that a means to some other end?

Comment: I don't see how your question have anything to do with OS X.

Answer (score 0):

that's a lot of code to go through.. but I add more identifiers to UIViews (ie other than the tag identifier) by using [obj-c runtime associative references](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_getAssociatedObject)..

So this is a category I attach to my UIView:

```
#import "UIView+Addons.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

#define kAnimationDuration 0.25f

@implementation UIView (Addons)

static char infoKey;
static char secondaryInfoKey;

-(id)info {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &infoKey);
}

-(void)setInfo:(id)info {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &infoKey, info, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(id)secondaryInfo {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &secondaryInfoKey);
}

-(void)setSecondaryInfo:(id)info {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &secondaryInfoKey, info, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

here is an example of my own code where I use the above to address a problem similar to the one you're facing:

```
    if (![[view info] boolValue]) {  // not selected?
        self.moveToFolderNumber = [view secondaryInfo];
        [view setInfo:@YES];
    }
```

Comment: I solved it my own way, I just add the doubleTapped object in to a array and checked every time when the doubleTapped GR gets called if the same object is in the array. But thanks, for your effort.